# Which is the difference between `min` and `nanmin`; `max` and `nanmax` in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Matlab describes `nanmin` and `nanmax` like this:

> **`NANMIN`** Minimum value, ignoring `NaN`s.
>
> **`NANMAX`** Maximum value, ignoring `NaN`s.

But in fact, `min` and `max` ignore `NaN`s too.

Which should I use then?

According to my tests, `nanmin` and `nanmax` are faster. Is it always like this?

Comment: @A.Donda `min` and `max` do ignore nan. Your example is about `mean`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`nanmin` just calls `min`:

```
[varargout{1:nargout}]=min(varargin{:});
```

Similarly for `nanmax`.  That's it!

In some past release, the built-in `min` and `max` were updated with the same functionality, ignoring `NaN`, and the toolboxes just started pointing to them instead of maintaining their own implementations. Just use `max` and `min`, unless you are working on special types that might have their own implementations of these functions.

Comment: To add the part about "which should I use": One should use `min` and `max` because they are part of core Matlab, while the wrappers `nanmin` and `nanmax` belong to the "Financial Toobox".

Comment: Statistics Toolbox also has it's own `nanmin` and `nanmax`.  At some point, the standard `min` and `max` gave the same functionality and the toolboxes just started pointing to them instead.

Comment: So Matlab changed the behavior of `min` to ignore `NaN`'s? How can they do that? It will no doubt break code.

Comment: @LuisMendo: This happened a *long* time ago: The [reference for Matlab 5](http://www.phys.ohiou.edu/computer/matlab/techdoc/pdfdocs/refbook.pdf) (PDF), which is copyrighted Dec. 1996, makes mention of `max` and `min` ignoring `NaN`.

Comment: @LuisMendo - Heck, maybe I'm imagining it, and they have always had these pointless stubs.  I can't find a pre-5 version.  I never thought I would have to check.