# Variable appears to change size on every loop iteration - what?

Tags: matlab, memory-management, iteration

When writing the following Matlab code:

```
for ii=1:n
    x(ii) = foo( ii ); % foo is some function of ii that cannot be vectorized.
end
```

I get the following [m-lint](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mlint.html) warning:

> The variable `x` appears to change size on every loop iteration

My question:

1. What does that warning mean?
2. Why is changing variable size every iteration is a bad thing?
3. How can this problem be solved?

---

This question is not duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171356), since it deals with more general aspects of preallocation, rather a specific instance of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preallocating arrays in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217017/preallocating-arrays-in-matlab)

Comment: Not a duplicate. `cell` preallocation is a different beast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MATLAB Matrix Preallocation Slower Than Dynamic Matrix Expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171356/matlab-matrix-preallocation-slower-than-dynamic-matrix-expansion)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, first thing first.

#### 1. What does this warning mean?

This code is correct in terms of syntax and it will execute correctly returning the expected result: the `ii`-th element of `x` will contain the value `foo( ii )`.
However, before this small piece of code runs, the variable `x` is not defined. Now, when the loop starts, `x(1)` is assigned the value `foo( 1 )`, and so Matlab creates `x` as a length-1 array. At the second iteration `x(2)` is assigned the value `foo( 2 )` and so Matlab needs to change `x` to be of length 2, and so on: `x` changes its length/size at each iteration.

#### 2. Why is changing variable size every iteration is a bad thing?

Consider what happens in the background (in terms of memory allocation) when `x` changes its size every iteration: At each iteration Matlab needs to find a free memory space to host the new size of `x`. If you are lucky, there is enough free space right after `x` so all that happens is a change to the amount of memory allocated to `x` and writing the new value at the right spot.
However, if there is not enough free space just after `x`, Matlab has to find a new spot for **all** the `ii-1` elements already in `x`, allocate this new space for `x`, **copy** all `ii-1` values already in `x` to the new spot, and free the old spot `x` used. This allocate-copy-free operations happening in the background can be extremely time consuming, especially when `x` is large.

#### 3. How can this problem be solved?

The simplest solution is to pre-allocate all the space `x` needs **before** the loop:

```
x = zeros(1,n); 
for ii=1:n
    x( ii ) = foo( ii );
end
```

By pre-allocating we ascertain that `x` is allocated all the memory it requires up-front, thus no costly memory allocation/copy is needed when the loop is executing.

#### An alternative cool solution to the problem

If you are too lazy (like me) and don't want to pre-allocate you can simply:

```
for ii=n:-1:1
    x( ii ) = foo( ii );
end
```

This way, the first time `x` is assigned a value it is assigned to its `n`-th element (the last one) and therefore Matlab **immediately** allocates room for all `n` elements of `x`.
Cool!

Comment: Another solution is to right click on the highlighted portion of code and select "Suppress ..." etc. from the menu to stop the warning. In some cases dynamic memory allocation can't easily be avoided or just isn't worth it for short inexpensive calculations. In current versions native dynamic memory allocation can be extremely fast and even faster than some other dynamic allocation methods.

Comment: @horchler I would consider that to be more of a workaround than a solution. (Depending on what you believe the problem to be). In almost all cases where I do short calculations and it won't lead to problems I would just reverse the loop. Quite a minimal effort.

Answer (score 14):

My answer is a bit late, but there are a few things I'd mention regarding array growth and pre-allocation in MATLAB.

The first thing to note is that MATLAB has improved automatic array growth performance a lot in recent versions, so the performance hit implied by the warning might not be too bad *if* you do it right (see below).  Still, best practice is to pre-allocate your array (e.g. with `zeros`).

### The Warning Explained

As of R2014a, the detailed explanation for the warning states the following:

> The size of the indicated variable or array appears to be changing with each loop iteration. Commonly, this message appears because an array is growing by assignment or concatenation. Growing an array by assignment or concatenation can be expensive. For large arrays, **MATLAB must allocate a new block of memory and copy the older array contents to the new array** as it makes each assignment.
>
> Programs that change the size of a variable in this way can spend most of their run time in this inefficient activity. ...

From this excerpt, it should be fairly clear why pre-allocation is a smart idea if you are at all concerned with performance.

Side note: There is limited information about the algorithm used for reallocation during array growth, but some information was provided on the same blog post by Steve Eddins, which I summarized in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061025/2778484).

### Automatic Array Growth Optimization

If you want to use dynamic array resizing by growing along a dimension (without-preallocation), there are ways to do it right.  See this this [MathWorks blog post by Steve Eddins](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/05/20/more-about-automatic-array-growth-improvements-in-matlab-r2011a/).  The most important thing to note is that you should **grow along the last dimension for best performance**. This is not an issue in your case since the array is 1D.  So, if you decide to let it ride, put `%#ok<SAGROW>` on the same line as the warning, after the culprit code, to silence the warning.

Yair discusses dynamic array resizing in [another post on his blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/array-resizing-performance/). Also, there are ways of allocating an array without initializing using some hairy MEX API acrobatics, but that's it.

### Pre-allocation

Pre-allocation is recommended. Get in the habit, learn to love `zeros`. If you are determined to squeeze every bit of performance out of MATLAB, Yair Altman has a couple of excellent articles on the topic of memory pre-allocation:

- [Preallocation performance](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance/)
- [Preallocation performance and multithreading](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/allocation-performance-take-2/)

Comment: @LuisMendo I liked this post too. ;) One the most annoying aspects of SO is that a post like this often gets minimal recognition while a post like [this junk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19696227/2778484) will get tons.  Completely inexplicable! [shrug]

Comment: I agree that it's annoying. Like @Shai says, [life isn't fair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202652/life-isnt-fair)

Answer (score 7):

There is a lot of material out there on the subject. Here are a few selected links for more information:

Official documentation and technical solutions:

- [Techniques for Improving Performance: Preallocating Arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html#f8-793781)
- [Strategies for Efficient Use of Memory: How to Avoid Fragmenting Memory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/strategies-for-efficient-use-of-memory.html#brh72ex-41)
- [How do I pre-allocate memory when using MATLAB?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99124)

MathWorks Blogs:

- [Automatic array growth gets a lot faster in R2011a](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/05/16/automatic-array-growth-gets-a-lot-faster-in-r2011a/)
- [More about automatic array growth improvements in MATLAB R2011a](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/05/20/more-about-automatic-array-growth-improvements-in-matlab-r2011a/)
- [Understanding Array Preallocation](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2012/11/29/understanding-array-preallocation/)

Community Blogs:

- [Preallocation performance](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance/)
- [Array resizing performance](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/array-resizing-performance/)
- [Speed up your Code by Preallocating the size of Arrays, Cells, and Structures](https://web.archive.org/web/20111016012735/http://blinkdagger.com/matlab/matlab-speed-up-your-code-by-preallocating-the-size-of-arrays-cells-and-structures/)

Related Stack Overflow questions/answers:

- [Appending a vector to an empty MATLAB matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/783137/97160)
- [Matrix of unknown length in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549094/97160)
- [What is the alternative to preallocating arrays in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3251232/97160)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is simplified sparing some of the details.

1. M-lint warns the programmer when it spots an opportunity to pre-allocate  memory.  Pre-allocating memory improves processing time as it simplifies tasks outside of a MATLAB programmer's direct control related to memory hardware management.
2. A changing variable size is not always bad; however, it is good programming practice to code for faster processing speed. Faster processing speed is more noticeable when the code uses many iterations or much more memory.
3. Other MATLAB pre-allocation methods recommended will work; however, the following methods may be more intuitive.

   - Assigning a value to a pre-allocated array.

     ```
     x(1:n) = NaN; 
     for ii=1:n
         x(ii) = foo(ii); 
     end
     ```

     Notes:

     - Assigning NaN while pre-allocating may be advantageous because an NaN is found in the array means the value was not allocated.
     - When pre-allocating in one dimension ones(n), zeros(n), or NaN(n) will allocate a n x n matrix.  If working with an extremely large dataset this can slow computation speed.
   - Assigning a value to a pre-allocated multi-dimensional array:

     ```
     x(1:n_i,1:n_j) = NaN;  % or NaN(n_i, N_j);
     for ii=1:n_i
         for jj=1:n_j
             x(ii,jj) = foo(ii,jj); 
         end
     end
     ```
   - A lazy way to pre-allocate is to assign a zero to only the last element in an array.

     ```
     x(n)= 0;
     for ii=1:n
         x(ii) = foo(ii); 
     end
     ```

Comment: You can create an array of `NaN` simply by `NaN(m,n)` instead of `x(1:m,1:n)=NaN`.

Comment: I like to use x(1:m,1:n)=NaN because of the one dimensional behavior of NaN(), ones(), or zeros.  When in one dimension NaN(m) allocates an m by m matrix.  When working with long datasets this is way too much memory which is capable of dragging down the program speed.   Though this approach is more elegant, it is inconsistent.