# MATLAB memory allocation: loop over mat-files

Tags: matlab, memory

I have `n` mat-files containing parts of a single huge matrix. I want to load the mat-files and concatenate the row,column,value-vectors to build matrix `W`. Right now, I'm doing the following, but it's really slow and I know I shouldn't dynamically increase the size of `rows`,`cols`,`vals`:

```
rows=[];cols=[];vals=[];

for ii=1:n
    var = load( sprintf('w%d.mat', ii) );
    [r,c,v] = find( var.w );

    rows = [rows; r];
    cols = [cols; c];
    vals = [vals; v];
end

W = sparse( rows, cols, vals );
```

Do you know a better way? Thanks in advance!

**Solution**

Based on Daniel R's suggestion, I solved it like this:

```
rows=zeros(maxSize,1);
cols=zeros(maxSize,1);
vals=zeros(maxSize,1);
idx = 1;

for ii=1:n
    var = load( sprintf('w%d.mat', ii) );
    [r,c,v] = find( var.w );        

    len = size(r,1);
    rows(idx:(idx-1+len))=r;
    cols(idx:(idx-1+len))=c;
    vals(idx:(idx-1+len))=v;
    idx = idx+len;
end

W = sparse( rows, cols, vals );
```

Extremely fast, thanks a lot!

Comment: actually the code is not valid matlab. it should be 
`for ii = 1:n`

Comment: Please give the profile results of which lines take most time. Also give the relevant sizes of variables in those lines and check how often these lines are called.

Comment: The `rows=[rows;r];` commands were my problem. I solved it and will update my post accordingly!

Comment: relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023171/variable-appears-to-change-size-on-every-loop-iteration-what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preallocate an array. Assuming `r`,`c` and `v` have the size a*b each.

In total, you need a*n rows and b columns, thus preallocate using `rows=nan(a*n,b)`

To write the Data into the array, you have to set the correct indices: `rows((ii-1)*a+1:ii*a,1:end)=r`

Comment: The problem is I don't know the dimension of `r`,`c`,`v`. However, I guess this could work anyway, by allocating `rows`,`cols`,`vals` at a maximum size and determining the size of each sub-matrix on the fly. Thanks already, I'll try this and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas.

- It looks to me the matrices have the same sizes.
- Another bottleneck might be the `find` function.
- could it happen that two matrices have different values at the same index? That might lead to problems.

You could do:

```
 var = load( 'w1.mat' );
 W = var.w;
 for ii  = 2:n
    var = load( sprintf('w%d.mat', ii) );
    ig = var.w~=0;
    W(ig) = var.w(ig);
 end
```

in case `var.w` is not sparse add a `W = sparse(W)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To your remarks: 1. It's true that the matrices have the same size. 2. The find function is very fast and normally not a bottleneck. 3. Good catch, but fortunately this can't happen in my case.

Your solution works, but write access to sparse matrices in that way is very very slow and should be avoided because of the way sparse matrices are organised (more information [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/accessing-sparse-matrices.html) if you're interested).

Comment: I see - is your matrix small enough that you can have it in memory in full form? Then it might be faster.

Comment: No, that's not possible unfortunately. I found a solution in the meantime, thanks for your inputs, though!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick that sometimes helps to speed things up as if your variables were initialized. However, sometimes it just does not help so the only way to find out is to try:

Replace lines like:

```
rows = [rows; r];
```

by lines like:

```
rows(end+(1:numel(r))) = r;
```