# MATLAB - How to declare a matrix with "row slots" for me to insert rows?

Tags: matlab, matrix

In each iteration, I am inserting one row into a matrix whose row number is predetermined. My current implementation is

```
seqToBePutIntoMatrix = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
col_no = 3; % hence the matrix is 3x3
myMatrix = [];
for i = 1:col_no:length(seqToBePutIntoMatrix)
    myMatrix = [myMatrix; seqToBePutIntoMatrix(i:i+col_no-1)];
end
```

MATLAB is suggesting me that

> The variable `myMatrix` appears to change size in every loop iteration.
>   Consider preallocation for speed.

I am seriously considering its advice, and wish to preallocate such a 3-row empty matrix and insert one row in each iteration. I have tried this:

```
seqToBePutIntoMatrix = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
col_no = 3; % hence the matrix is 3x3
myMatrix = [];
j = 1;
for i = 1:col_no:length(seqToBePutIntoMatrix)
    myMatrix(j) = seqToBePutIntoMatrix(i:i+col_no-1);
    j = j+1；
end
```

However, this is not working. How may I make it work?

Comment: It's a good thing you considered Matlab's advice, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023171/variable-appears-to-change-size-on-every-loop-iteration-what)'s a short thread explaining why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subscripts `myMatrix(j)` references only a **single** element of `myMatrix`. In order to reference an entire row, you need

```
myMatrix(j,:) = seqToBePutIntoMatrix(i:i+col_no-1);
```

Moreover, you need to pre-allocate a 3-by-3 matrix **before** you start the `for`-loop

myMatrix = zeros(3,3);

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Answer (score 3):

You are still initiallizing `myMatrix` to an empty matrix (third line):

```
myMatrix = [];
```

To preallocate, you should initiallize the matrix to its final size:

```
myMatrix = NaN(3,3); %// or zeros(3,3), or ones(3,3), or ...
```

and then, within the loop, fill each row:

```
myMatrix(j,:) = seqToBePutIntoMatrix(i:i+col_no-1);
```