# How to declare an array without size in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I wan to declare an array in MATLAB without specifying the size, rather like `std::vector` in C++, and then I want to "push" elements to the array. How can I declare this array and push to it?

Comment: this is **very bad practice** in terms of memory allocation. Please consider pre-allocating.

Answer (score 6):

Altough the [answer of Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23805200/1714410) is correct, it is a **very bad practice** to let an array grow in Matlab without pre-allocation. Note that even `std::vector` has the option to [`reserve()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) memory to avoid repeated re-allocations of memory.

You might want to consider pre-allocating a certain amount of memeory and then resize to fit the actual needed size.

You can read more on pre-allocation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21023171/1714410).

Answer (score 4):

You can just define an empty array like this:

```
A = [];
```

To "push" a column element:

```
A = [ A 42 ];
```

To "push" a row element:

```
A = [ A ; 42 ];
```

Answer (score 4):

As [Shai pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806085/1714410), pushing elements onto a vector is not a good approach in MATLAB. I'm assuming you're doing this in a loop. In that case, this would be better approach:

```
A = NaN(max_row, 1);
it = 0;
while condition   
   it = it + 1;
   A(it) = value;
end
A = A(1:it);
```

If you don't know the maximum dimension, you may try something like this:

```
stack_size = 100;
A = NaN(stack_size,1);   
it = 0;

while some_condition 
   it = it + 1;
   if mod(it, stack_size) == 0
       A = [A; NaN(stack_size,1)];
   end  
   A(it) = value;
end
A = A(1:it);
```