# Why this multiplication is SO slow

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I want to multiplicate 2 matrices. I need to multiplicate them element by element. Their size is 100x100 . But why this function works very slow? About 2-3 minutes.

```
for i=1:size(volumes,1)
  for j =1:size(volumes,2)
      ys(i,j) = volumes(i,j)*prices(i,j)

  end
end
```

How to speed up this operation?

Comment: because it's an overkill. Just use `volumes.*prices`. Still, the loop shouldn't be that slow...

Comment: 2-3 mins for elementwise-multiplication of 100x100 matrices? Pentium 1 or 2?

Comment: 2-3mins for 10.000 Multiplications is to much. What kind of object are your matrices? Maybe their indexing operator does something expensive?

Comment: BTW, it is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the major problem is, that you forgot the semicolon `;` at the end of your line, where you do the calculation. So you are displaying the resulting `100x100` matrix `ys` **10000** times in your command window. That can take a looooot of time. (still 2-3min is even too much for that).

Also you should **preallocate** `ys`. Otherwise `ys` is growing in arraysize with every iteration, it can happen that the memory is not sufficient and the `ys` needs to be copied to a different location in memory, which also takes time. By pre-allocation you reserve space for the whole loop. You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023171/variable-appears-to-change-size-on-every-loop-iteration-what/21320980#21320980) interesting.

Therefore:

```
ys = zeros(size(volumes));
for i=1:size(volumes,1)
  for j =1:size(volumes,2)
      ys(i,j) = volumes(i,j)*prices(i,j);
  end
end
```

and it will work fine.

---

But apart from that **use the [elementwise-multiplication operator](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/times.html)** `.*`!

```
ys = volumes.*prices;
```