# How to remove those rows of matrix A, which have equal values with matrix B in specified columns in Matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have two matrices in Matlab A and B, which have equal number of columns but different number of rows. The number of rows in B is also less than the number of rows in A. B is actually a subset of A.

How can I remove those rows efficiently from A, where the values in columns 1 and 2 of A are equal to the values in columns 1 and 2 of matrix B?

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
for k = 1:size(B, 1)
     A(find((A(:,1) == B(k,1) & A(:,2) == B(k,2))), :) = [];
end
```

and Matlab complains that this is inefficient and that I should try to use `any`, but I'm not sure how to do it with `any`. Can someone help me out with this? =)

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
A(any(A(:,1) == B(:,1) & A(:,2) == B(:,2), 2), :) = [];
```

It complains the following:

```
Error using  == 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Example of what I want:

[image]

[image]

A-B in the results means that the rows of B are removed from A. The same goes with A-C.

Comment: `setdiff` is the best solution but to convert your first try to `any` (*keeping* your loop) this is what Matlab is suggesting (you'd actually want `all` and not `any` in your case): `A(all(A == B(k,:),2), :) = [];`

Comment: +1 Thank you very much @Dan I will try all the solutions and post the performance times =)

Comment: btw I didn't realize you were only comparing the first two columns so update my last comment to `A(all(A(:,1:2) == B(k,1:2),2), :) = [];`

Comment: Thank you everybody for your fine answers =) The original running time (with my data) was: 0.198072 seconds. By using the `bsxfun` approaches I got a running time of approximately 0.007 seconds. By using `setdiff(A(:,1:2),B(:,1:2),'rows')` I got the running time: 0.004120 seconds.

Comment: @jjepsuomi Hope you can do some benchmarks on bigger datasizes too, would be interesting to see those results too.

Comment: +1 @Divakar I will try with different data sets and post my results =) It will take few minutes =)

Comment: @Divakar results coming in soon =)

Comment: don't forget the `ismember` solution too...

Comment: @jjepsuomi Added one more `bsxfun` approach in my solution, so do you mind adding that too to your benchmark results? :)

Comment: Hi @Divakar I added the results for my datasets =) Okay I can add the one more `bsxfun` approach, just a sec =)

Comment: Hi @Divakar I added your second approach as well =) It seems `setdiff` is beating the heck out of all for some reason (with the dataset I have available). Maybe the results could be different if I had much larger datasets? =) Thank anyway for everybody! =) Your solutions are all very good and the performance differences aren't that big that it would make a difference (at least in my case =)).

Comment: @jjepsuomi I think the results certainly make sense, because `bsxfun` is known to be memory hungry, so with those huge datasizes, it's bound to get slower. `setdiff` with its definition looks perfect for this problem. Thank you for the results BTW!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html). for example:

```
c=setdiff(a,b,'rows')
```

Note, if order is important use:

```
c = setdiff(a,b,'rows','stable')
```

**Edit**: reading the edited question and the comments to this answer, the specific usage of `setdiff` you look for is (as noticed by Shai):

```
[temp c] = setdiff(a(:,1:2),b(:,1:2),'rows','stable')
c = a(c,:)
```

#### Alternative solution:

you can just use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
a(~ismember(a(:,1:2),b(:,1:2),'rows'),:)
```

Comment: +1 But don't you need `setdiff(A(:,1:2),B(:,1:2),'rows')` instead?

Comment: When I wrote my answer there was an example in the question of two arrays similar to those in the answer that are now edited out. That what I always write: "for example,..." if you understand the answer you can apply it to the question anyway.

Comment: @jjepsuomi Could post back on the screenshot image you had in the post before the edits?

Comment: bygones Divakar :) ... the question was answered 3 times already.

Comment: @natan I really thought the screenshot made it easier for everyone to understand.

Comment: @Divakar I posted the pic, but there's some problem in the server I think, because it doesn't display it?

Comment: @natan well that would give you first two columns only as `c`. Look into [Shai's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24300103/3293881), it has the correct setdiff implementation using the first two columns, I believe.

Comment: @natan Sorry, it was messy, but for correctness, it was necessary I guess :) I think you can keep it, but just state the assumption that its for all columns and not just first and second column. Upto you!

Comment: from all the mess I thought of an alternative solution with `ismember`... :)

Comment: @natan haha way to avoid the mess! Out of +1s :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun):

```
compare = bsxfun( @eq, permute( A(:,1:2), [1 3 2]), permute( B(:,1:2), [3 1 2] ) );
twoEq = all( compare, 3 );
toRemove = any( twoEq, 2 ); 
A( toRemove, : ) = [];
```

#### Explaining the code:

First we use `bsxfun` to compare all pairs of first to column of `A` and `B`, resulting with `compare` of size `numRowsA`-by-`numRowsB`-by-2 with `true` where `compare( ii, jj, kk ) = A(ii,kk) == B(jj,kk)`.
Then we use `all` to create `twoEq` of size  `numRowsA`-by-`numRowsB` where each entry indicates if **both** corresponding entries of `A` and `B` are equal.
Finally, we use `any` to select rows of `A` that matches at least one row of `B`.

#### What's wrong with original code:

By removing rows of `A` inside a loop (i.e., `A( ... ) = []`) you actually resizing `A` at almost each iteration. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023171/variable-appears-to-change-size-on-every-loop-iteration-what) on why exactly this is a **bad practice**.

#### Using [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html)

In order to use `setdiff` (as suggested by [natan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24300083/1714410)) on only the first two columns you'll need use it's second output argument:

```
[ignore, ia] = setdiff( A(:,1:2), B(:,1:2), 'rows', 'stable' );
A = A( ia, : ); % keeping only relevant rows, beyond first two columns.
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort =) Your answer is great! =)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `bsxfun` implementation -

```
A(~any(squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq,A(:,1:2),permute(B(:,1:2),[3 2 1])),2)),2),:)
```

One more that is dangerously close to [Shai's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24300103/3293881), but still avoids `two permute` to `one permute`  -

```
A(~any(all(bsxfun(@eq,A(:,1:2),permute(B(:,1:2),[3 2 1])),2),3),:)
```

Comment: @natan haha Thanks and likewise here :)