# How to filter a monotonic increasing vector for a certain minimum rise between two consecutive values?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector with more than 1000 rows like this:
`N = [13120; 13157; 13200; 15124; 17128; 19108; 19130; 21112; 23096: ... ]`

The problem I have here is that I need to find (and extract) just values which are rising by *2000+-20*, so I created a vector `M = [13120; 15120; 17120; 19120; 21120; 23120]`. Here I think I don't have the right solution because, for instance, after 1000 iterations the number in my new vector won't match anymore. I would need to correct the value after approximately 10 iterations and then compute a new vector which goes up in a step of 2000.

At the end, I need to extract just the proper rows and delete the others like:

```
NewVector = [13120; 15124; 17128; 19130; 21112; 23096]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you couldn't avoid a while loop.

```
N = [13120; 13157; 13200; 15124; 17128; 19108; 19130; 21112; 23096]

%// parameters
x = 20;
X = 2000;

%// initialize
Z(1) = N(1);
ii = 1;

while (Z(ii) +X - x) < N(end)  %// check if last value of new vector is still 
                               %// smaller than biggest value of initial vector
    Z(ii+1) = N( find(N > (Z(ii) + X - x) ,1 ) );  %// find next biggest
                                                   %// with minimum rise of
                                                   %// X - x              
    ii = ii+1;                                     %// increase counter
end
```

gives:

```
Z' =

       13120
       15124
       17128
       19130
       21112
       23096
```

---

Until now there is no [**preallocation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023171/variable-appears-to-change-size-on-every-loop-iteration-what), I don't know how fast the loop is in your case. To improve performance you could add:

```
%// initialize
Z = zeros(numel(N),1);    %//preallocate with largest possible vector

...

while ...
      ...
end

Z = Z( 1:ii );            %//remove remaining zero values
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer so much!! It gives me an error message "Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix." but I will try to solve it.

Comment: I got this as well, it actually shouldn't happen anymore. you could include `while Z(ii) < N(end); if ~isempty( find(N > (Z(ii) + X - x) ) ...` in your loop.

Comment: in order to eliminate the mentioned error, you should include a different condition in a while loop:`while (Z(ii) +X - x) < N(end)`