# Saving all values generated by a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, mean

So, I am new to MatLab and I am trying something of which I am sure it is possible. I'm not sure how though.

Here's what I'm trying in a nutshell: I generate a string of outcomes (M) from matrix C. Matrix C consists of 16 cells (4x4 cells, each cell is 90x6). From each of these cells I try to compute the mean value. This gives me the mean values, but rewrites M after each iteration:

```
for i=1:4;
for j=1:4;
M=mean2(C{i,j})
end
end
```

What I need is a matrix of 4x4 wherein the mean values for all of C's cells are listed, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
M = zeros( 4 ); %// pre-allocate !!!
for ii=1:4;
    for jj=1:4;
        M(ii,jj)=mean2(C{ii,jj})
    end
end
```

A few pointers:

1. Pre-allocation - it is a very good practice to pre-allocate arrays that are being updated in loops.
   See, for example, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023171/variable-appears-to-change-size-on-every-loop-iteration-what).
2. It is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).
3. You might find [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) a useful tool when working with cell arrays:

   ```
   M = cellfun( @mean2, C );
   ```

Comment: well done for the `ii` and `jj`, although I never use them myself, I always forget to remind people that they are not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1) To preallocate as @Shai said:

```
M = zeros( 4 );
for ii=1:4;
    for jj=1:4;
        M(ii,jj)=mean2(C{ii,jj})
    end
end
```

2) To append to the previous element in the array

```
M = [];
for i=1:4;
for j=1:4;
M=[M;mean2(C{i,j})];
end
end
```

Method 1 is definitely way better. But wanted to inform you there are two methods..