# Define a matrix before a loop when one dimension in unknown

Tags: matlab, loops, variables, matrix

I want to assign some values to a matrix in a loop, but I don't know how many. `B` is a vector that's calculated based on a data set `Data(i,:)` inside a loop. The number of elements in `B` is fixed inside the loop, but is unknown beforehand.

It is like;

```
A = zeros(n,m) %// I know n but I do not know m
for i = 1 : n
    % some code to calculate B from Data(i,:)
    A(i,:) = B;
end
```

`B` is a vector, but I don't know `length(B)` before the loop so I can't assign it to `m`.
When I initialize `A = [];`, Matlab gives a warning

> `A` appears to change size in every loop iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `B` has a fixed length, one alternative is:

```
A = zeros(n,[]);
for ii = 1:n
   A(ii,1:numel(B)) = B;
end
```

This way you will preallocate the number of rows, and after the first iteration, the number of columns will be fixed as `numel(B)`.

**So, why does `A(ii,1:numel(B)) = B` work and `A(ii,:) = B` doesn't?**

When you do `A(ii,:) = B`, you're trying to place the vector `B` in row number `ii` of `A`. For this to work, the number of columns must be equal in `A` and `B`. You can think of it as:

```
A(ii,:) = B
```

is equal to

```
A(ii,1:end) = B(1:end);
```

If you start out with an empty array `A`, or an array with n rows, but zero columns, the two `end`s won't be equal and you will get a dimension mismatch.

If, however, you do `A(ii,1:numel(B)) = B`, you specifically say that you're trying to place the vector `B` in the columns 1 to m in row number `ii` in `A`. Now, since `B` has more columns than `A`, MATLAB will auto-pad the remaining matrix with zeros.

You can try some yourself. Don't copy-paste, try one after the other so that you can see how `A` changes after each line. Hope this clears things up!

```
A = []
A(2,1) = 3
A(1,3) = 2
A(3,:) = [5 6 7]
A(:,6) = [1; 2; 3]
A(3,:)
A(3,1:end)
A(:,3)
A(1:end,3)
```

Comment: @Kamtal, Glad I could help! I gave some examples in the end that works. You might learn a lot by trying things you don't necessarily expect to work. You often learn more from error messages that from working code. Try for instance `A = [6 7 8 9]`, `A(1:0)`, `A(1:5)`, `A([1 1 2 1 1 2])`, `A([1 0 1 0])` and `A(logical([1 0 1 0])`. Try to understand what's happening. What happens if you do: `A(logical([1 0 0])` (three elements instead of four)?

Answer (score 2):

You can also reverse the order of your loop, without any pre-allocation

```
for ii=n:-1:1
    A(ii,:) = B;
end
```

This way, the first time `A` is accessed Matlab actually access the **last** row and therefore knows exactly the final size of `A`, `A` will not change size during iterations.

See this trick [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023171/variable-appears-to-change-size-on-every-loop-iteration-what).

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).