# Numerical grouping using matlab / octave and not repeating values found in main array

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave, numerical-methods

I have about 100,000 numbers that I would like to group together based on dividing by two or increments of two.
PS: The increment values may change and the values found in the main array **"x"** can only be used once.
**I'm not sure how to check and stop the loop if a number in the "array_all" array has been repeated from the "x" array.**

See example below

Example:

```
x=[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

**I'm trying to get the array_all array to look like this:**

```
array_all= 
[  9.00000   4.50000   2.25000
   8.00000   4.00000   2.00000
   7.00000   3.50000   1.75000
   6.00000   3.00000   1.50000
   5.00000   2.50000   1.25000
   1.00000   0.50000   0.25000]
```

**and the dynamically named arrays to look like this**

```
array_dyn_name1=[9,4.5,2.25]
array_dyn_name2=[8,4,2]
array_dyn_name3=[7,3.5,1.75]
array_dyn_name4=[6,3,1.5]
array_dyn_name5=[5,2.5,1.25]
array_dyn_name6=[1,.5,.25]
```

**PS: The reason I don't just stop at the array "array_dyn_name6" is due to that the numbers will not be that simple there will be thousands.  And I won't know when they will repeat.**

Sequence of events:
1. Start from the highest number in the **x** array and divide that number and it's output number by two and place that into another array called **array_all**, do this 3 times
2. Place each row of **array_all** into a dynamically named array called **array_dyn_name**
3. Do this for each value in the **x** array unless the number has already been used before in the **array_all** array

Note: As you can see the **array_all array** don't start with 4,3, or 2 because they were previously used in the **array_all array**

The code below works but **I'm not sure how to check and stop the loop if a number in the "array_all" array has been repeated from the "x" array.**

```
%test grouping
clear all, clc, tic, clf; 

x=[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
div=[1,2,4] %numbers to use as divisor
array_all=[];
for ii=1:length(x)

    for jj=1:length(div)
        array_all(ii,jj)=x(ii)/div(jj) %divide each number and successive number by div 
    end

    genvarname('array_dyn_name',  num2str(ii)) %create dynamic variable
    eval(['array_dyn_name' num2str(ii) '= array_all(ii,:)']) %places row into dynamic variable 

end
fprintf('\nfinally Done-elapsed time -%4.4fsec- or -%4.4fmins- or -%4.4fhours-\n',toc,toc/60,toc/3600);
```

My output is below:

```
array_all =

   9.00000   4.50000   2.25000
   8.00000   4.00000   2.00000
   7.00000   3.50000   1.75000
   6.00000   3.00000   1.50000
   5.00000   2.50000   1.25000
   4.00000   2.00000   1.00000
   3.00000   1.50000   0.75000
   2.00000   1.00000   0.50000
   1.00000   0.50000   0.25000
```

PS: I'm using octave 3.8.1 it's like matlab

Comment: in your example, I can't see `1` appearing in `array_all`? So, why don't you include `1` in your example? i.e., `array_dyn_name6 = [1, .5, .25]`?

Comment: @Shai thanks for the catch your correct it should be included, i added it

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
array_all = bsxfun( @times, x(:), [1 .5 .25] ); %// generate for all values
```

Now, using [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) we prune the rows of `array_all`

```
[Lia Locb] = ismember( x(:), reshape( array_all.', [], 1 ) ); %// order elements of array_all row by row
```

By construction all elements of `x` are in `array_all` but we want to prune rows for which the first element already appears in previous rows.

```
firstRowToAppearIn = ceil(Locb/3);
```

So

```
toBePruned = 1:numel(x) > firstRowToAppearIn; %// prune elements that appear in array_all in a row preceding their location in x

array_all(toBePruned,:) = []; %// remove those lines
```

Now we can define `array_dyn_name`-s according to `array_all`.
[Using `eval` is HORRIBLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7kmd5), instead we use [structure with dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7asxm-1):

```
st = struct();
for ii=1:size(array_all,1)
    nm = sprintf('array_dyn_name%d',ii);
    st.(nm) = array_all(ii,:);
end
```

---

It seems like `ismember`'s second output (`Locb`) might be ordered differently between Matlab and octave (and maybe between newer and older versions of matlab). So, here's an alternative, using [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun):

```
eq_ = bsxfun( @eq, array_all, permute( x(:), [3 2 1] ) );
eq_ = max( eq_, [], 2 ); %// we do not care at which column of array_all x appeared
[mx firstRowToAppearIn] = max( squeeze(eq_), [], 1 );
```

---

PS,
Apart from using `eval`, there is another cavity in your implementation: you do not pre-allocate space for `array_all` - this may cause your code to run significantly slower than it actually needs to be. See, for example [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21023171/1714410) about pre-allocation.

Comment: I'm getting an out of bounds error in the line  array_all(toBePruned,:) = []; %// remove those lines which seems not to take out the duplicate values in  array

Comment: @RickT it's a nasty thing about the last line: 1 appears before in the line `[4 2 1]` but this line is also removed. I'm afraid loop is the only way here,,,

Comment: thanks so much this has really helped so a for loop is what I need to adjust this

Comment: Due to an issue popping up with the answer another question has been created as to keep it understandable.  Here's a link to the new question that was recommended I include.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280544/how-not-to-repeat-values-in-array-using-matlab-octave?noredirect=1#comment44915757_28280544