# Variably name histogram in for loop

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to have a hist function in a for loop because I work with varying amounts of datasets each time and its much faster and easier that having to edit a script each time, but I can't get it right. Can I have some help please? In essence I'm trying to have this in a for loop for variable number of `unc{i}` datasets and i number of `[h{i},x{i}]` resulting arrays:

```
[h1,x1] = hist(unc1,range);
[h2,x2] = hist(unc2,range);
[h3,x3] = hist(unc3,range);
[h4,x4] = hist(unc4,range);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanking you in advance

Comment: So you want to loop through unc1 to unc4 and assign the histgram output to h1 to h4? Is that correct?

Comment: well, yes. But I may have anywhere from 4 to 100 different unc(i), that's why I need a loop.

Comment: What dimension does unc(i) have? Is it consistent?

Comment: The length is not constant. Its experimental data actually, so its always 1 x X  (X events recorded at each run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Desclaimer: the use of `eval` is [dangerous](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html)!**

Let's say you have `n` `unc`s arrays. You can use struct to store them

```
for ii=1:n
    cmd = sprintf( 's.unc%d = unc%d;', ii, ii );
    eval( cmd );
end
```

Once you have the `unc`s is a sttruct, you can simply

```
for ii=n:-1:1
    [h{ii} x{ii}] = hist( s.(sprintf('unc%d',ii)), range );
end
```

---

**Notes:**
1. Note that I used a backward loop for computing the histograms: this is a nice trick to preallocate `h` and `x`, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21023172/1714410).
2. It is extremly unwise to use `eval`, therefore, it might be wiser to create the different `unc`s arrays as a struct fields to begin with, skipping the first part of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put each of your input datasets in a cell array, and the output of the histograms in a second cell array.

For example,

```
unc1 = rand(5,1);
unc2 = rand(5,1);
unc3 = rand(5,1);
unc_cell = {unc1, unc2, unc3};

h_cell = cell(3, 1);
x_cell = cell(3, 1);
for ii = 1:3
    [h{ii} x{ii}] = hist(unc_cell{ii}); 
end
```

This does require preloading all of the datasets and holding them in memory simultaneously. If this would use too much memory, you can load the datasets in the for loop rather than preloading them.

For example,

```
h_cell = cell(3, 1);
x_cell = cell(3, 1);
for ii = 1:3
    unc = load(sprintf('data_%d.mat', ii)); %You would replace this with your file name 
    [h{ii} x{ii}] = hist(unc); 
end
```

Comment: I tried that already, but each of the datasets is a few million points long and I have memory issues with more than 6-7 of them. Thank you both for your time!! You saved me loads of time already